# Javascript n00b - Get YouTube API v3 Video Description instead of Title (existing code)

Tags: javascript, youtube

With apologies for asking what I imagine will be a stupid (or seemingly lazy) question.
I fully grant you that the problem here lies in my inability to understand JavaScript. I promise you... I'm working on it. I'm learning JS slowly. :) I'm thankful for any help you can give.

I'm using an existing script to create a YouTube playlist.

However, instead of displaying the video's title (which is what the code currently does), I want to display the video's description.

I really thought this would be easy. But alas... it's beyond me.

With hope that this doesn't bring an onslaught of -1's...
Chris

```
function(dummy_code_so_I_can_post_a_JSfiddle-link){};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nk9a1dyh/

Comment: Is there any way you could post some code that isn't minified? The JS in the JSFiddle is horribly cryptic.

Comment: Thanks for having a look, theWanderer4865. Sorry, all I have to work with in the minified code. It's horrible, I know. Welcome to the hell that has been the last three hours of my life. :/

Maybe I should resolve to build my own player, instead of blindly copying someone else's code.
Thanks again for looking.

Comment: Ok, now I know what you are trying to do. I'll post an answer for you shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are looking to target is:

`var d=e.entry["media$group"]["media$description"].$t;`

see updated (still horrible) jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nk9a1dyh/3/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup!! That did it.
Unfortunately, it doesn't carry over the paragraph formatting of the descriptions, which is a little heartbreaking.
(Totally in agreement that the jsfiddle is horrible... Thanks for giving it a go).

Comment: Sadly the JSON object which contains the description does specify that the description is of type/plain `{"$t":"VIDEO DESCRIPTION - You've done it. Holy crap, you've done it!!! :D","type":"plain"}` - Uncomment //console.log(...) on line 31 to see the object in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to make this far more complicated then it has to be.

First off, try to get your HTML together - it is the scaffold you will run your JS on.

Second, making an API call in JS from the browser can be quite difficult so take baby steps. Start off installing [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org) and use the `http` or `requests` library to make a simple request to the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started). Here is a simple example to show you what you are doing:

```
var http = require("http");
var my_response = http.get("http://google.com/");
console.log(my_response)
```

Really take the time to understand all the stuff in this JSON object. Things like status code, content-type, headers, all of these things mean something important to how your application can know what is happening.

Once you are comfortable, look in the Videos resource in the API docs and see what you get back when you make a get request. Once you are comfortable with using the API, then you can move on to making your application do work.

Comment: Thanks for this.
I think it's time for me to start again from scratch. :)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't give your answer the check mark. In some ways, it is the most correct answer: "become familiar with what you're doing; understand every bit of it". If I could give out two check marks, I would. Cheers.